# How to remove all/single event listners in socket.io

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, hapi.js, eventemitter

I am using socket.io for realtime functionality in my app with hapijs. When I am trying to add a listner on server side in a hapijs route and if I reload the same route/page 10 times or more then it starts showing me an error `(node:9004) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 board_5a40a863a7fbf12cf8a7f1b8_element_sorted listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit`. you can also see error in attached screenshot. 
[image]

I tried each of following codes to removeListners first and then add it back using `socket.on('eventname', callback)`:

```
io.sockets.removeListner("eventname")

io.removeListner("eventname")

socket.removeListner("eventname")

io.sockets.removeAllListners()

io.removeAllListners()

socket.removeAllListners()
```

But I got an error everytime that `removeAllListners/removeListner is not a function`.
I also tried setting limit of maxlistners to unlimited by using each of following codes:

```
io.setMaxListeners(0);

io.sockets.setMaxListeners(0);

socket.setMaxListeners(0);
```

But I still kept getting the same error of `memory leak detected`. So can somebody tell me the solution for this. I would preferably like to follow the approach of removing the event listeners first and then setting it back. But I don't know which function do I need to call. :(

Also I want to know one more thing, is it a good approach create a new and unique event listener for every user rather than creating a common event listener of all the users?

For example I have a chat app with 1 million users.

1. Now in first approach I will have to create 1 million event listeners for 1 million users. So whenever there is a new message from a user then only those users will get the ping from the server who are chatting with that user.
2. In second approach I will have to create 1 common event listener for all users, but now server will have to ping 1 million users now and I will have to parse the message received every time on client end and check whether the message is for me or for somebody else.
   According to me 2nd approach should not be a good approach because of security issues as there are chances of a message being received by a wrong/unauthorized user.

But still I am not sure which one to follow.
So, can anyone guide me on this thing well. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: No, it's not a good idea to create an event listener for each user. I'm not sure even why you're doing that...? Could you provide your full code please? I think removing listeners is not the right approach, because it seems that what you are currently doing might be a bad idea.

Comment: We need to see your actual code in order to advise what you should change to fix your problem.  If you are adding an event listener inside another event listener or inside a route handler, then immediately stop doing that as it is the wrong way to do things.  We can advise the correct way only when we see your actual code.  Questions about code SHOULD include relevant portions of your own code.